# render string as html in cell of react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using typescript. I'm having a column value in the table as

```
val desc = "<div><p>testing</p></div>"
```

I want to render this as `testing` in value. I'm using

> `react-table`

I tried `new DOMParser().parseFromString("<div><p>testing</p></div>", "text/html")`
But got error as

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> HTMLDocument]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use
> an array instead

Here is my react-table code:

```
<Table
        data={data}
        headers={headers}
        searchable={true}
        searchPlaceholder={'Search Apps'}
        toolBarButtons={toolBarButtons}
      />



const headers = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>{checkbox}</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Checkbox',
        disableSortBy: true,
      },
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>Name {sortIcon}</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Name',
      },
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>Type {sortIcon}</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Type',
      },
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>Tenancy {sortIcon}</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Tenancy',
      },
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>Description {sortIcon}</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Description',
      },
      {
        Header: <LeftHeader>Action</LeftHeader>,
        accessor: 'Button',
        disableSortBy: true,
      },
    ],
    [],
  )

    const data = useMemo(() => {
    return List.map((ap) => {
      const actionButton = (
        <Edit
          size={20}
          cursor={'pointer'}
          color={'#1E95DE'}
          onClick={() => setRedirectUrl(RouteConstants.Marketplace + '/' + ap.id)}
        />
      )
      checkbox = <input type={'checkbox'} onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, ap)} />;
      return {
        Checkbox: checkbox,
        Name: ap.stuName,
        Type: options.filter(e => e.value === ap.stuType).map(f => {
          return f.label
        }),
        Description: ap.studescription,
        Tenancy: titleCase(ap.stuTenancy),
        Button: actionButton,
      };
    })
  }, [List])
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why `desc` is defined as `"<div><p>testing</p></div>"` (string) and not as `<div><p>testing</p></div>` (React element)? If not, just remove the quotes and you should be fine.

Comment: yeah, there is a reason. It will be not just this much its like a description of any application

Comment: Does this question really belong to `react-table` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) which is unsafe, prone to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.

```
let desc = "<div><p>testing</p></div>"
// ...
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: desc}} />

// or in React Table Cell
{
  Header: <LeftHeader>Description {sortIcon}</LeftHeader>,
  accessor: 'Description',
  Cell: ({row}) => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.original.Description}} />
},
```

You can do it if you trust the source of your HTML string. It should not be a user provided input.

Comment: I had to do this: 

Cell:  function renderDescription(row: any) {
          return (<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: row.row.original.Description }} />)
        }

Comment: @PuneetMehta Yes, right. You need to do `row.row` in React Table V7. I have updated my answer. You can also use `({row})`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two another choice here.

One of theme is to use states. I would like to recommend you to use "redux".

For example (Using pure react states):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
export const App = props => {
   const [desc, setDesc] = useState('<div><p>testing</p></div>');
   return <element>{desc}</element>
}
```

And the other one is innerHTML by [Ref or DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
const desc = "<div><p>testing</p></div>";
export const App = props => {
   const myRef = useRef(null);
   useEffect(() => {
      myRef.current.innerHtml = desc; //using Refs
      //or
      document.getElementById('myID').innerHTML = desc; //using DOM
   }, [])
   return <element id="myId" ref={myRef}>{desc}</element>
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code. How can I use it in react-table